# Purge Pinta in 16.04

Tags: apt, purge, pinta

I installed and removed pinta, the image editor. I removed it using:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove pinta
```

I thought this would remove *all* vestiges of the program. But it still shows up when I run `sudo apt-get update` there is an endless list of pinta-maintainers it is seemingly trying to install, with a bunch of junk I don't want to be seeing any more. For instance:

```
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                         
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                            
Fetched 1,004 kB in 9s (105 kB/s)                                                                                                               
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Further, when I open the software updater, under the `Other Software` tab, there are still two checkboxes for pinta:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu main
http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu main (Source Code)
```

Why are they still there, and what can I do to stop this? If I just click "remove" will that be sufficient, or will I just be hiding some deeper evil?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to both my problems is found in the question:
In the `Software Updater`, go to the first pinta maintainer line, click remove. All of the above problems go away.