# apt-get update issue with pinta repository

Tags: apt, pinta

After running `sudo apt-get update`, I get this issue:

```
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu bionic Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                     
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta- stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

I don't currently have Pinta installed, though. I uninstalled it via terminal after installing it a while back. I tried re-installing via the Ubuntu Software App, still got the same issue, I tried uninstalling it through it, still the same issue. I'm not sure why it displays that, and I don't know how to fix this error so I can get rid of this. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: It means that PPA has no package for your release of Ubuntu. Delete the PPA - it's worthless to you now. Uninstalling the package does not delete the PPA that provided the package. Pinta has been in the Ubuntu repositories for a very long time - you never needed a PPA for it.

Comment: My question is actually a duplucate of this, it seems: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007159/purge-pinta-in-16-04

Answer (score 3):

This PPA is totally outdated and don't support Ubuntu 18.04 bionic.

The best way to remove a PPA is by installing ppa-purge then:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable
```

Alternatives are:

- Installing pinta from Ubuntu repos (Version 1.6-2)
- Installing pinta from flatpak (flathub) (Version 1.6)
- Building it from source https://pinta-project.com/pintaproject/pinta/howto/building-pinta

Comment: `ppa-purge` for some reason didn't work for me, but going through `Software & Updates`, under `Other Software` and unticking pinta's line did the trick, thanks!

Comment: ppa-purge makes sure to remove all packages from the PPA before removing the ppa itself. But in your case you didn't install packages from the PPA and it's probably not working because it's configured "bionic" but the PPA don't support bionic !